# Can't import Django model into scrapy project

Tags: python, django, import, scrapy, python-import

I have a folder `Project` which contains `Django` project called **djangodb** and `Scrapy` project called **scrapyspider**.

So it looks like:

```
Project
    djangodb
        djangodb
        myapp
    scrapyspider
        scrapyspider
            spiders
            items.py
        scrapy.cfg
    __init__.py
```

I want to import model `Product` from `myapp` app in `items.py`

The problem is that it returns import error:

```
from Project.djangodb.myapp.models import Product as MyAppProduct
```

> ImportError: No module named djangodb.myapp.models

Tried many things but couldn't avoid this error. Do you have ideas?

Comment: did you try deleting `Project`

Comment: Yes I did. It not helped

Comment: it seems to be an error from `settings.py` do you have a similar import to check if everything is fine?, where is located this line?

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's in items.py

Comment: the problem is that Django manage the routing inside its project, if you want to import the models you have to put `items.py` inside djangodb folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to do an import from a file that's outside from  Django schema, to solve that you can overwrite the `sys.path`var which includes locations as the actual dir, so you can change it to:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\your_path\\Project')
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/Project/') # Linux

# And then import #

from djangodb.myapp.models import Product as MyAppProduct
```

Comment: I have tried this solution on my MAC but didn't work for me.